# NLog: reference properties in message

Tags: nlog, serilog, structured-logging

I am using NLog with structured logging for the first time. I user Serilog in the past, and with that I could write something like this:

```cs
Serilog.ILogger logger = CreateSerilogLogger();
logger.ForContext("MyProperty", "Some dummy value")
      .Information("This is the value: {MyProperty}");   // prints out: "This is the value: Some dummy value"
```

but with NLog it seems I cannot reference properties in the log message. This is what I tried to do:

```cs
NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.WithProperty("MyProperty", "Some dummy value")
      .Info("This is the value: {MyProperty}");   // prints out: "This is the value: {MyProperty}" !!!
```

I know I could simply pass the string inside `Info` method; this is just an example.

Is there a way to achieve this with NLog? Can properties passed with `WithProperty` method be linked inside the log message?

Comment: NLog only uses the formatting-args provided with the log-message when formatting the log-message. This also allows NLog to skip parsing of all log-messages when no formatting-args provided (Better performance).

Comment: thanks @RolfKristensen. Is performance the only reason why they do this?

Comment: Also when providing a large blob-string without any parameters, then NLog will not spent time on parsing and complaining if the blob is not in valid message-template-format.